# Progress bar UserControl Inside another UserControl does not fire Tick event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, backgroundworker

I am implementing the progress bar control in my windows app.
Here's how my progress bar code looks like .

```
public partial class ProgressBar : UserControl
{
    public event Action OnCommand;

    private int _progressInitial = 0;

    private int _progressMaximum = 100;
    #region :: Member Methods ::
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
        _progressBar.Value = 0;

        if (!_backWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            _lblProgressText.Text = string.Empty;
            _backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void End()
    {
        if (_backWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _backWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #endregion

    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progressBar.Maximum = _progressMaximum;
        _backWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _backWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void _backWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.OnCommand != null)
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => OnCommand()));
        if (_backWorker.CancellationPending)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void _backWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _lblProgressText.Text = string.Format("{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
            _progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void _backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progressBar.Value = _progressMaximum;
        _lblProgressText.Text = string.Format("{0}%", _progressMaximum);
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_backWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            _progressInitial += 10;
            if (_progressInitial >= _progressMaximum)
                _progressInitial = 99;
            _backWorker.ReportProgress(_progressInitial);
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

### Parent UserControl

```
public partial class Sample : UserControl
{
    public Sample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.End();
    }

    private void progressBar1_Command()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

---

This is a `UserControl` and in my `DoWork` of the background worker I do a long database operation on a parent control which fires the `OnCommand` event operation .

This `OnCommand` handler will contain the long database operation which is why I use the timer to update the progress bar for certain interval.

This works fine if I use the control directly on the Form

But if I use this control inside another `UserControl` where the usercontrol contains

1. Start and End Button
2. The ProgressBar control with OnCommand event implemented (DB Operation)

The moment the OnCommand method gets executed the timer stops ticking.

Is there any relation as to why it works on a Form and not inside a `UserControl`?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Francis P.

Comment: Why do you call `this.Invoke` in the `_backWorker_DoWork` event?

Comment: I was just trying out to see if there is any change. Even if i simple do a this.OnCommand() it still does not work

Comment: Calling `this.Invoke` in the `_backWorker_DoWork` event defeats the purpose of the background work thread. The [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method just posts the delegate call to be executed in the UI thread. Have you placed break-points in the event `_backWorker_DoWork` event handler? On what thread does it execute? Also, did `_backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` not execute while `OnCommand` executed? (something that will happen if you call `this.Invoke`)

Comment: Thanks Francois for your reply .Even if i remove the Invoke method and use the this.OnCommand() it still does not make any difference . This executes but the timer ticker TICK method does not get executed . 
I just checked if the RunWorkerCompleted gets executed YES it does but the time tick event does not so progress is shown ?

Comment: But then there is your problem. If the RunWorkerCompleted get executed you stop the timer... or am I missing something? Also make sure the delegate attached to OnCompleted does not post actions to the UI thread that will block it. Remember this version of the Timer you are using executes its OnTick events on the UI thread and if that (the UI thread) is blocked the Tick event still waits in the message queue...

Comment: Yes on RunWorkerCompleted i stop the timer and update the ProgressBar Value to maximum . 
I use the delegate Action 
I have updated my code where in it shows the parent user control with the event handler OnCommand implemented .
Is there anything missing or incorrect in it ?

Comment: No, I can't see something wrong with it (at least not what may be the cause of the problem)

Comment: Does your UI seem to lock up if the timer stops?